# Method to determine is the square of a persons age == to the current year

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that determines if the square of the age of a person is equal to the current year. For example  a man was aged 43 in 1849 and the square of 43 is 1849.
Below is my code for it but I dont know why my exception is not working because it is assumed that no body can live past 123 years

```
 public Boolean isAlive(int y){
     assert( y>=1888 && y<=2134);
     int age=0;
     while(age<=123){
         y=y+1;
         age=age+1;
         if(age*age==y){
             int c=age;
             return true;
             }
         }
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: If you assume that nobody can live past 123, then your while is wrong: you go to `age=123`, but then you do `age=age+1`, so age would be 124. Your code kinda goes to 11 :)

Comment: i'm not sure why you chose the name isAlive for this method.

Comment: @nanne  i have changed it to age<123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve appears to be

```
y + n = n^2
```

where `y` is the starting year and `n` is the age and both must be a positive whole number.

Rearranged this is

```
n = (sqrt(1 + 4 * y) + 1)/2;
```

e.g.

when y = 1806, n = 43, n + y = n * n = 1849.

when y = 1980, n = 45, n + y = 2025, n * n = 2025.

So you can write

```
public boolean squareAgeIfBorn(int year) {
   double n = (Math.sqrt(1 + 4 * year) + 1) / 2;
   return Math.abs(n - (long) n) < 1e-9; // i.e. if n is a whole number.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it much easier:

```
 public boolean isAlive(int age){
    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return year == age * age;   
 }
```

Comment: because he wants to know if the age of the person in square is the current year?

Comment: @Roflcoptr `Math.pow` is a slowish method meant for approximation when you're raising some double to a power which may or may not be a whole number. If you just need the square of an int, multiply the number by itself.

Comment: That's how you square something in Java. The `*` operator only *multiplies*, duh! ;p

Comment: @wds ok i see you can replace Math.pow(age, 2) with age*age

Comment: my design is to ask the user for the date of birth of user  and then add 1 to both the date of birth and age each and then compute the square of the age and check if its equal  to the current year,My method currently works but the exception is not working.The date of birth is meant to be between the current year-123 and current year +123

Comment: This method will not return true until the year 2025 and you are 45. ;)

Comment: It will return true for example for 43 and 1849 as in the example of the OP. But maybe I didn't understood the question correctly...

Comment: @Roflcoptr, You are using the system clock which you would have to set to 1849. ;) It appears to me that the year is an input.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Yes I use the current year because in the Question it is mentioned that ''square of a persons age == to the current year''. And yes I tested it with 1849 but not with the system clock ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't catch your code but from description I think you want to check if square of someone's age is equal current year

1. don't use assert
2. count square of the age
3. get current year
4. compare if 2 == 3